# jinja2: Writing data in tag attribute within a loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a result object looking like this:

```
result = [{
    start: 0,
    length: 2
}, {
    start: 5,
    length: 3,
}]
```

I need to create a html tag like this:

```
<div starts="0|5"></div>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<div starts={ {% for res in result %}{% if loop.index0 %}'|'{% endif %}{res.start}{% endfor %} }>
<div starts={{ for res in result } '|' if loop.index0 {res.start}{ endfor } }>
```

and several other variations. How can I achieve my goal? I´m new to jinja, so excuse this maybe "stupid" question. :-)

Comment: Do you need to loop for this? Is it possible that the `result` objects contains other than exactly two elements? What should happen then? Can’t you construct the final string on the Python side to reduce the complexity in your template?

Comment: I do not have access to the Python side and there is several other information in the result. The result object can contain any number of elements. Is it even possible to loop at this point?

Comment: If there can be any number of elements, how exactly is the string constructed then?

Comment: What do you mean by "how exactly is the string constructed then"? The attribute value should look like "0|5|17|34", depending on the elements of the result.

Comment: That’s what I wanted to know since it wasn’t clear from the question how it should behave for an element count other than 2…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to collect the `start` attributes of all the objects inside `result` and join them by a pipe character, then you can simply use the [`join` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#join) for this:

```
<div starts="{{ result | join('|', attribute='start') }}"></div>
```